# Multi-threaded Counting Sort

Tags: sorting, counting, partition

I have a university assignment that requires me to code the Counting Sort algorithm with *n* threads in Java. We haven't really been given more information than that. I thought that the best way would be to partition the array into *n* sections, then each thread sorts a section. The problem is that I am unsure of how to partition the array properly; I have only seen examples on how to partition into 2 sections, not *n* sections.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide me with the logic on how to partition it like I've explained, or give some pseudo-code. No source code please, this is an assignment I have to do.

I have no problem with the actual sorting, just the partitioning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Definitions

Let's say that you have an array `a[0..n-1]` to sort and you want to do it using `k` threads.

For simplicity, let's assume that the smallest element has value 0 and the largest have a value `m`. If the smallest is not equal 0, then you can scale the values during assigning elements to threads.

### Splitting into threads

Partition your array into `k` chunks each consisting of at most `floor(m/k) + 1` different values of elements.

The `i-th` chunk consists of elements `a[j]` such that:

`(i - 1) * (floor(m/k) + 1) <= a[j] < i * (floor(m/k) + 1)`

For example, if you have an array with 10 elements:

`a[0..9] = {1, 2, 5, 0, 3, 7, 2, 3 ,4, 6}` and `k = 3`, then `m = 7` and the 3 chunks are:

```
chunk_1: elements in range [0,3) -> [1, 2, 0, 2]
chunk_2: elements in range [3,6) -> [5, 3, 3, 4]
chunk_3: elements in range [6,9) -> [6, 7]
```

Next, assign each chunk to a separated thread. Each thread sorts one chunk and to get the whole array sorted, just concatenate the results from all threads in order:

`thread_1` `thread_2` `...` `thread_k`

### Complexity:

As you know, the complexity of the count sort is `O(n + L)` where `n` is the number of elements to sort, and `L` is the maximum value of element.

First, notice that you can scale down values in each thread in such a way, that `L < floor(m/k) + 1` in that thread, so the complexity of count sort in each thread always depends on the number of elements in that thread.

If you assume that the distribution of the values is uniform, then the expected number of elements in each thread is also `floor(m/k)` so the total complexity of each thread is `O(m/k)`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Just a question about chunk size: you said that each chunk has floor(m/k) + 1 elements. In your example this would be 3 elements. However, your chunks have 4. Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea popping into my mind is to partition the array recursively. That means if you can partition into 2, you can also partition into 4 , right?

A more advanced and modern approach is to partition into many more parts than you have threads or processes. Then assign these parts dynamically to the threads.

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm not sure how to correctly partition them. For Example I have this array: {37, 1, 27, 11, 15, 12, 34, 29, 4, 10}. After partitioning it I get this: {10,1,4,11,15,12,34,29,27,37} (the pivot point was the average). Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @Mr_Bean: You rearranged the array rather than partinioning (at least I would not call it partitioning ;) ). Anyways. Think of the result as two arrays: {1,4} and {11,15,12,34,29,27,37}. The pivot element 10 can be added two either one. Then you repeat that with the new arrays. Also look up "merge sort"...

Comment: oh okay, thanks. I saw an implementation where they rearranged the array so the partitions are the same size (or off by 1). Will give this a shot.